# 4-bit counter on EPWave

Tags: verilog, counter, system-verilog

I did a 4-bit counter module in Verilog, and I need to represent on EPWave the following steps:

- the clock is toggled every 1 second
- the counter works for 5 seconds, then the reset is on, then the counter gets on for 12 seconds.

```
module contador_sequencial(
    input clk,
    input reset,
    output reg [3:0] count
);

  always@(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
    if(reset) begin
      count <= 4'b0000;
    end else if (count == 4'b1001) begin
      count <= 4'b0000;
    end else begin
      count <= count + 1'b1;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

```
module testbench;
  reg clk;
  reg reset;
  wire [3:0] count;
  
  contador_sequencial counter(.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .count(count));
  
  initial begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #1000 clk = ~clk;
  end
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
    reset = 0;
    #5000
    reset = 1; 
    #1000 
    reset = 0;
    #12000 
    $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

The counter was supposed to be counting initially for 5 seconds, but this is what I'm getting:

[image]

in the first 5 seconds, it doesn't count at all. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

During the 1st 5 seconds, `count` is unknown (`x`) because you declared the signal as a `reg` type, and that type initializes to `x` in simulation.  Since `reset` is 0 during that time, you do not execute the reset clause:

```
if(reset) begin
```

Therefore, `count` remains unknown until time=5s.  At time=5s, you set `reset`=1 in the testbench, which means `count` is set to 0.

Typically, the testbench would assert the reset signal starting at time 0, then deassert it after a few clock cycles:

```
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
    reset = 1;
    #5000
    reset = 0; 
    #13000 
    $finish;
  end
```